# Java Node String Validation

Tags: java, string, tree, nodes

I have been given a TreeNode in the form of a string and need to do a validation on the string to see if it is indeed correct before doing any operations on it.
My program works fine in representing the tree and I have sorted out other exceptions like double commas etc, but some exceptions of invalid trees are giving me a hard time.

**Test 1:**

```
"(,1)2"
```

Easy to check with:

```
str.contains"(,"
```

**Test 2:**

```
"(1)2,(3)4"
```

?

**Test 3:**

```
"(1,2)3,4"
```

?

The last 2 tests are giving me a headache on how to approach them. I tried using a stringbuilder to check without the numbers, but the problem is that there are correct trees that use the same bracket and comma combos (For example "),(" which is corrent in the tree +(+(+(1,2),3),+(4,5))...)

Is it possible to check them somehow with before doing an operation like the others or do I need to do it somewhere inside while iterating the nodes?

PS: They have to be all-rounders, meaning that the numbers could be anything. So I can't just put in the whole string and cheat

Answer (score 0):

Can you use regex expressions?

**Test 2:**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\([0-9]\)[0-9],\([0-9]\)[0-9]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
boolean found   = matcher.find();
```

**Test 3:**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\([0-9],[0-9]\)[0-9],[0-9]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
boolean found   = matcher.find();
```

Comment: I can, but it's still kinda specific to one certain node build, the problem in both string is the comma placement and I think they are asking for a fit-all solution (for example the two commas could be anywhere in any string), which is why this is giving me a headache.

Comment: You will need to cycle through the string and handle each char by itself. There isn't a simple cookie cutter solution, you will have to actually design an algorithm to do this.
Expect to write a few methods, perhaps some recursive methods, to find the correct solution.

Stackoverflow isn't here to do your homework, so you're best cause of action is to design the algorithm using your preferred method (paper and pen, pseudo code, hacking it out). Get help from fellow students !